# Android - Shared Preferences won't load my options

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, settings, user-input

I have four buttons(ImageView) inside a popup window, each button will change the the color of a button in my service class to the desired color. When I click one of these buttons it will change the color but when I exit from the app en start it again, my option is not saved.

```
 //Inner class inside my MainActivity 
 public static class  SetReng {

  static  int reng;


    public  SetReng() {

    }



    public int getReng() {
        return this.reng;
    }
}

public void onGreen (View view) {
    SetReng.reng = Color.GREEN;
    ImageView Green = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.kesk);
    Green.setPressed(true);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bloq color set to green", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    editor.putInt("Which", SetReng.reng);
    editor.apply();


}
```

Here's the code in my service that should load the color options

```
    SetReng putReng = new SetReng();
    int theReng= putReng.getReng();

    SharedP= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    int colorOp= SharedP.getInt("Which", theReng);



    mButtondeh= new Button(this);
    mButtondeh.setBackgroundColor(colorOp);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm stuck with this for the last couple of days so anything will be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried logging or debugging?

Comment: I've just tried it; saving the values to the shared preferences goes checked but retrieving the values in the service class doesn't. What does it mean?

Comment: you must be using a different context when saving and loading.

Comment: Maybe, because in my MainActivity the context is getPreferences(Context.Mode_Private) but in my service it PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); Do you think that's the reason why? if so what's the solution?

Comment: use PreferenceManager in both cases; the other one is specific to the activity.

Comment: Thanks for help. I solved it by replacing getReference() manager with getSharedPreference() and in my service, I changed PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); to SharedP = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
...
editor.putInt("Which", SetReng.reng);
editor.commit(); // instead of apply
...
```

Comment: I changed it to .commit() but still nothing happens :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing getReference() manager with getSharedPreference() and in my service, I changed PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); to SharedP = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); And now it works perfectly!